# NumberFormatException while reversing a negative number

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt()
    String s=new StringBuilder().append(n).reverse().toString();

    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(s));
```

I am trying to reverse a number but when I try to give negative numbers for example if I give input as -124 it gives me NumberFormatException. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: The string `-124` reversed is `421-`, which is not a valid number.

Comment: Why not print the reversed string to see what you are trying to parse ?

Comment: COBOL supports numeric data items with 'SIGN IS TRAILING SEPARATE' but AFAICS not REVERSE on them -- but you could use overlay or redefinition :-}

Answer (score 0):

Reverse of `-X` is `X-` hence the `-` at the end of string is causing the `NumberFormatException`.
Here is a simple ways to handle both positive & non-positive numbers:

```java
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        // Make `n` positive if `n` is negative
        String s = new StringBuilder().append(n<0 ? -n : n).reverse().toString();
        // Print the reverse string along with `-` sign if n<0
        System.out.println((n<0 ? "-" : "") + Integer.parseInt(s));
    }
```